# why result not getting in spring data application

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am newbie to spring and java,

I have a case, where i am trying to fetching rows from the mysql table

This is my **Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pharmacy/order/dates", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public PharmacyOrderDateResponse orderDates(@Valid @RequestBody PharmacyOrderDateRequest request) {
        List<PrescriptionOrder> pharmacyOrders = prescriptionOrderService.orderDatesByPharmacyId(request.getPharmacyId(), request.getOrderStatus(), true);
        if(pharmacyOrders.size() == 0) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("No pharmacy orders found");
        }
        PharmacyOrderDateResponse response = new PharmacyOrderDateResponse();
        Set<Date> orderDateSet = new HashSet<>();
        for(PrescriptionOrder pharmacyOrder : pharmacyOrders) {
            //orderDateSet.add(longToDate(pharmacyOrder.getCreatedAt().getTime()));
        }
        response.setPharmacyId(pharmacyOrders.get(0).getPharmacyId());
        response.setStatus(ResponseStatusCode.SUCCESS);
        response.setPharmacyOrderDateDetails(orderDateSet);
        response.setTotalDates(orderDateSet.size());
        return response;
    }
```

The above controller is used to call the service by the function, so that to get the list of prescription orders.

This is my **Service**:

```
package com.axonytes.corporate.service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.axonytes.corporate.entity.PrescriptionOrder;


public interface PrescriptionOrderService {

    List<PrescriptionOrder> orderDatesByPharmacyId(Long labId, String orderStatus, Boolean status);

}
```

This is my **ServiceImpl**:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class PrescriptionOrderServiceImpl implements PrescriptionOrderService {

    private PrescriptionOrderRepository prescriptionOrderRepository;


    @Autowired
    public PrescriptionOrderServiceImpl(PrescriptionOrderRepository prescriptionOrderRepository) {
        this.prescriptionOrderRepository = prescriptionOrderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<PrescriptionOrder> orderDatesByPharmacyId(Long pharmacyId, String orderStatus, Boolean status) {
        OrderStatusEnum orderStatusEnum = OrderStatusEnum.fromString(orderStatus);

        List<PrescriptionOrder> prescriptionOrder = prescriptionOrderRepository
                .findByPharmacyIdAndOrderStatus(pharmacyId, orderStatusEnum.getStatus());
        return prescriptionOrder;
    }

}
```

The above service is a implementation function to list the orders, where it calls the repository function.

This is my **Repository**:

```
package com.axonytes.corporate.repository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.axonytes.corporate.entity.PrescriptionOrder;

@Repository
public interface PrescriptionOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PrescriptionOrder, Long>{

    //@Query(value = "select * from PrescriptionOrder po WHERE po.pharmacyId = :pharmacyId AND po.orderStatus = :orderStatus AND po.active = :active ORDER BY po.createdAt ASC")
    //List<PrescriptionOrder> findByPharmacyIdAndOrderStatus(@Param("pharmacyId") Long pharmacyId, @Param("orderStatus") int orderStatus, @Param("active") Boolean active);
    List<PrescriptionOrder> findByPharmacyIdAndOrderStatus(@Param("pharmacyId") Long pharmacyId, @Param("orderStatus") int orderStatus);

}
```

This is my **Entity**:

```
package com.axonytes.corporate.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "prescription_orders")
public class PrescriptionOrder extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3853355500806579362L;

    @Column(name = "prescription_id")
    private Long prescriptionId;

    @Column(name = "pharmacy_id")
    private Long pharmacyId;

    @Column(name = "order_status")
    private int orderStatus;

    public Long getPrescriptionId() {
        return prescriptionId;
    }

    public void setPrescriptionId(Long prescriptionId) {
        this.prescriptionId = prescriptionId;
    }

    public Long getPharmacyId() {
        return pharmacyId;
    }

    public void setPharmacyId(Long pharmacyId) {
        this.pharmacyId = pharmacyId;
    }

    public int getOrderStatus() {
        return orderStatus;
    }

    public void setOrderStatus(int orderStatus) {
        this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
    }

}
```

This ismy **OrderStatusEnumClass**:

```
package com.axonytes.corporate.util;

public enum OrderStatusEnum {

    PENDING(0, "pending"), DESPATCHED(1, "dispatched");

    private int status;
    private String name;

    OrderStatusEnum(int status, String name) {
        this.status = status;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static OrderStatusEnum fromString(String name) {
        if(name != null) {
            for(OrderStatusEnum orderStatusEnum : OrderStatusEnum.values()) {
                if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(orderStatusEnum.toString())) {
                    return orderStatusEnum;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

I have row values in the mysql:

```
id prescription_id pharmacy_id order_Status is_active
1  1               6           0            1
```

I am trying to list a orders by the following api.

```
http://localhost:8080/pharmacy/order/dates
```

POST METHOD with JSON VALUE:

```
{
    "pharmacyId":"6",
    "orderStatus":"pending"
}
```

Eventhough i am having 1 rows in the mysql db table, Output i am getting is:

```
{
  "status": "FAILURE",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": "No pharmacy orders found"
}
```

Comment: please show `OrderStatusEnum` class

Comment: set hibernate log to DEBUG and you will see as some exception is happenig

Comment: @degr OrderStatusEnum Class added

Comment: I suppose that `@RequestBody` is `superfluous`

Comment: Look like everything ok. Try to uncomment your spring data query, and hardcode values there: `@Query(value = "select * from PrescriptionOrder po WHERE po.pharmacyId = 6 AND po.orderStatus = 0")`

Comment: @degr when i debug the code and check i get the following bugs. "Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from com.axonytes.corporate.entity.PrescriptionOrder po WHERE po.pharmacyId = 6 AND po.orderStatus = 0]

Comment: The pharmacyId that you pass from the form should be Long and not string. Can you try and change it to "pharmacyId":6 instead of "pharmacyId":"6"

Comment: type `select po from PrescriptionOrder po WHERE po.pharmacyId = 6 AND po.orderStatus = 0` or better type `select * from PrescriptionOrder po`

Comment: Try to configure `Hibernate` to show generated `SQL`. You can achive this by enabling property `showsql`

Comment: when i try just by select * from PrescriptionOrder po, i get the following Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [select * from com.axonytes.corporate.entity.PrescriptionOrder po]

Comment: also when i type 'select po from PrescriptionOrder po' i get the following error. {
  "status": "FAILURE",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": "Parameter with that position [1] did not exist; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that position [1] did not exist"
}

Comment: to my surprise when i comment the query tag, and just run by jpa query, i get the following results. {
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "totalDates": 0,
  "pharmacyId": 6,
  "pharmacyOrderDateDetails": []
}

Comment: in my controller, i have the following line orderDateSet.add(longToDate(pharmacyOrder.getCreatedAt().getTime()));, this show the error: this method longToDtate(long) is undefined for the type PrescriptionOrderController

Comment: @telex where and how can i add the property showSql

Comment: @user3929758 check your column names are exactly the same you have in your tables

Comment: `Parameter with that position [1] did not exist;` mean that you should remove `@Param("pharmacyId") Long pharmacyId, @Param("orderStatus") int orderStatus` from method declaration

Comment: @degr you mean like this, @Query(value = "select po from PrescriptionOrder po")
 List<PrescriptionOrder> findByPharmacyIdAndOrderStatus();

Comment: yes .............

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using spring data and name method resolving. So is spring who translate the name of your method with each property in your entity, in that case you don't have to declare any parameter name so change your method to this:

```
@Repository
public interface PrescriptionOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<PrescriptionOrder, Long>{

    List<PrescriptionOrder> findByPharmacyIdAndOrderStatus(Long pharmacyId, int orderStatus);

}
```

Note: You have an enum OrderStatusEnum but you are saving into the database an integer, I highly recommend you to modify the object to store and change the int for the enum, would be easier to read